Executing a 3D U-net I get widely different metrics in each execution, sometimes >99,99% across accuracy, recall, DICE and IoU
I have created a custom 3D U-Net for multi-class semantic segmentation. Currently, I'm using it for medical image classification, where only two classes are present. I have two related issues: with each training, I get widely different scores for the metrics, and sometimes those scores are >99.99%. Even when I execute the exact same code with the exact same input, I fail to get consistent results.
To be more precise, I get three different types of scores each time I run the training:

A very strong first epoch, with the rest quickly achieving >99.99% scores.
A very weak first epoch (<1%), which after some time achieves >99.99% scores.
A normal first epoch (between 60% and 80%, depending on the metric) that improves slightly during training.

These results appear in the training, validation, and test sets, so I don't think overfitting is the issue. Also, when I predict the masks from the original data, I'm not even close to getting good results (as one would expect with a 99.99% score). As a final note, most of the metrics I use are pre-defined Keras/TensorFlow metrics.
I'm unsure what additional information might be needed to understand what's happening here, but if you can help me, I would appreciate it greatly. Specifically, I want to:

Understand why the results vary so much.
Understand why the results reach 99.99% when the segmentation performance is not nearly that good.

All the code of the Unet can be found in the following block
''' 3D U-net for binary semantic segmentation'''

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Conv3DTranspose, concatenate, BatchNormalization, ReLU, Dropout, UpSampling3D
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import IoU
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

# Custom Dice coefficient metric
def dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + 1) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 1)

# Custom IoU metric
def iou_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    union = K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) - intersection
    return (intersection + 1) / (union + 1)

# U-net model for 64x64x64 images using the first custom architecture
def UNET_64x64x64_custom1(input_shape, n_classes):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    # Encoding path
    c1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
    c1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)
    
    c2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
    c2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
    
    c3 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
    
    c4 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c4)
    
    # Bottleneck
    c5 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c5)
    
    # Decoding path
    u6 = UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2))(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c6)
    
    u7 = UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2))(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c7)
    
    u8 = UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2))(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
    c8 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c8)
    
    u9 = UpSampling3D((2, 2, 2))(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
    c9 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
    c9 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c9)
    
    outputs = Conv3D(n_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    return model

def custom_weighted_categorical_crossentropy(weights):
    weights = K.variable(weights)

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
        y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        cce = y_true * K.log(y_pred)
        weighted_cce = cce * weights
        return -K.sum(weighted_cce, axis=-1)

    return loss

def main():
    # Parameters model
    input_shape = (64, 64, 64, 3)
    architecture = UNET_64x64x64_custom1
    epochs = 1
    batch_size = 4
    # Parameters input
    input_dir = "data/Input"
    img_file = "ADCs.npy"
    mask_file = "Masks.npy"
    # Parameters output
    output_dir = 'output'
    model_name = "output/model.h5"
    # Binary classification
    n_classes=2
    
    # Read files
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    input_img = np.load(os.path.join(input_dir, img_file))
    input_mask = np.load(os.path.join(input_dir, mask_file))
    
    # Combine the first two dims to get N images
    train_img = np.stack((input_img,)*3, axis=-1)
    # Images to three channels.
    train_mask = np.expand_dims(input_mask, axis=4)
    # Binary masks to categorical.
    train_mask = (train_mask > 0).astype(np.uint8)
    train_mask_cat = to_categorical(train_mask, num_classes=n_classes)

    # Divide training data between train and validation sets
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(train_img, train_mask_cat, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 0)

    # Train
    model = architecture(input_shape, n_classes)
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss=custom_weighted_categorical_crossentropy([0.5005, 564.4044]),
        metrics=[
            'accuracy',
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
            iou_metric,
            dice_coefficient,
            IoU(num_classes=2, target_class_ids=[0,1])
        ]
    )
    model.summary()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                validation_data=(X_val, y_val), 
                epochs=epochs, 
                batch_size=batch_size
    )
    model.save(model_name, include_optimizer=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We want to use the relative path of the file (instead of the project one).
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    os.chdir(current_dir)

    main()

